# Convert Unix timestamp into datetime

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have the following data frame

```
> head(try)
     creates       time
1  128.29508 1417392072
3  236.98361 1417392072
7   98.45902 1417392072
9  157.44068 1417392131
10 227.38333 1417392131
11 242.03390 1417392131

> str(try)
'data.frame':   102968 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ creates: num  128.3 237 98.5 157.4 227.4 ...
 $ time   : Factor w/ 26418 levels "1417392071","1417392072",..: 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 5 5 ...
```

I am unable to convert the UNIX timestamp into datetime using the following methods I tried

```
> head(as.POSIXlt(as.numeric(try$time),origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT"))
[1] "1970-01-01 00:00:02 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:02 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:02 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:03 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:03 UTC"
[6] "1970-01-01 00:00:03 UTC"

> head(as.POSIXct(as.character(try$time),tz="GMT"))
```

> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
>         character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

```
> head(as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(as.vector(as.numeric(try$time)),origin="1970-01-01")))
[1] "1970-01-01 00:00:02 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:02 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:02 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:03 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:03 UTC"
[6] "1970-01-01 00:00:03 UTC"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here.

Comment: For a solution based on **lubridate** [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lubridate) package, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998206/r-lubridate-converting-seconds-to-date `lubridate::as_datetime(try$time)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to convert from Factor to Character To Number before using as.POSIXct. The function is expecting an integer as a Unixtime

```
head(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(try$time)), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"))
```

Comment: I'd tried that too and ended up with an error; > head(as.POSIXct(as.character(try$time),origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT"))
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 2):

It's because the epoch is not numeric, try converting it into a number and it works like wonder!

```
try$time <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(try$time), origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'GMT')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
head(as.POSIXct(as.integer(as.numeric(as.character(try$time)) / 1000.0), 
origin='1970-01-01', tz="GMT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
library("anytime")
anytime(try$time)
```

you can also get the date from the timestamps `anydate(try$time)`

and if you want UTC, you can do 
`anytime(try$time, asUTC = TRUE)`