# Convert Windows time into readable format using r?

Tags: r, date, time

I have Windows tick time in milliseconds like `13228488488553` (which should be `12/03/2020 13:08:08` at 1 or 2s approximately). As Windows clock the origin is 1/1/1601. I would like to see it in a readable date/hour format using everything (i.e. not rounding up to seconds, but up to milliseconds). A perfect example format would be `DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS.MSS`

I did not find any package doing it, and I tried manually but I am stuck with roundings and leap years. Does anyone know a package or did already do it with a handmade function?

Comment: there is a answer here? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998206/r-lubridate-converting-seconds-to-date

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that lubridate allowed specifying the origin. I tried putting 13228488488553 but get "420795-02-11 16:42:33 CET". I'm trying to find something in the options.

Comment: Update: I found the issue, must specify the time in seconds and not milliseconds. Is there an option to specify milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `as.POSIXct` from base R:

```
format(as.POSIXct(ticktime/1000,
                  origin = "1601-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
       format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "12/03/2020 12:08:08.552"
```

**Edit**: Perhaps this is your timezone:

```
format(as.POSIXct(ticktime/1000,
                  origin = "1601-01-01", tz = "CET"),
       format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "12/03/2020 13:08:08.552"
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the origin is 1601... I will edit the original message to indicate it.

Comment: Can you also edit your question to what the actual expected date is?